# How to run a function jQuery when scroll to top of page

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollbar

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I am trying to integrate a facebook-app like feature to my webpage where if you scroll beyond the top of the page it will refresh the page asynchronously.

All I need is a way to use a javasript/jquery/whateverelsewillwork to detect when the user scrolls up, even when the scrollbar is already at the top of the page.

regards,

taylor

Comment: Have you tried Searching the Site for `endless scroll` or `infinite scroll` - the idea is the same but instead of looking for the user to scroll to the bottom of the page, alter the code to look for the user to scroll to the top.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that binding events onScroll can lead to major performance issues.  The event can potentially fire several hundred times within a very short timespan when dragging the scrollbar slowly on a document.  Check out http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it, it is possible. All you need to do is to hook into the document's events and do some special cases checking. It was only tested on Chrome and IE9, I'll let you do the rest.

*If you want, you can use an existing jQuery mousewheel plugin instead to make your life easier. It should be more reliable if the plugin is kept up to date.*

```
$(function(){
    //This variable is used to prevent event flooding
    var preventRefire = false;

    //Bind all possible events
    $(document).bind("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel scroll keyup",function(event){
        //If an event was fired recently, return
        if(preventRefire) return;

        if(event.type == "keyup"){
            //If key is not up arrow or page up, return
            if(event.which != 38 && event.which != 33) return;

            //If an input field is focused, don't fire, return
            if($('input:focus,textarea:focus').length != 0) return;
        }

        if(event.type == "mousewheel" || event.type == "DOMMouseScroll"){
            //Guess scroll direction
            var deltaY = 0;
            if(event.wheelDelta) deltaY = event.wheelDelta;
            if(event.detail) deltaY = -event.detail;

            //If user mousewheeled down, don't fire, return
            if(deltaY <= 0) return;
        }

        //Finally, are we at the top?
        if($(document).scrollTop() == 0){
            //Prevent event to refire within 2 seconds
            preventRefire = true;
            setTimeout(function(){ preventRefire = false; }, 2000);

            //This is where you do your stuff
        }
    });
});
```

You can try a live demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/34p6B/2/

**Problems:**

It is somewhat reliable, just a couple of things to think about.

It wasn't tested on a mobile device, but the binding into the scroll event should handle it ok.

Due to event bubbling, mousescroll events will fire on other elements. For example if you have scrolling content in a text area or element *AND* you're at the top of the page, it *WILL* fire if you scroll the inner content up, even though it should not count as an "overscroll" on the document itself. In those cases you can use `event.stopPropagation()` on the scrolling elements' mousewheel event to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: Fantastic. This is great. Thank you for commenting the script as well. I'm just wondering, how why do you need to bind the events here, I am unfamiliar with the binding you have done here

Comment: I'm binding the events to the document element, because by default all events end up there, unless `event.stopPropagation()` is called or one of the handlers returns false. For example if you have `<ul><li><a></a></li></ul>` and click on `<a>`, It will fire `<a>`'s click then `<li>`'s click then `<ul>`'s click and if it's not stopped, it will eventually fire `document`'s click. Document is the best place to catch global events, giving you an option to stop the event bubbling before it hits it if you choose to.

Comment: The list of events in `bind()` is just a shorthand form to bind the same function to multiple events, saves me having to define a function and bind it to the events one by one, I can just use an anonymous inline function.

Comment: Personally I'd keep the binded triggers, and remove the if checks except $(document).scrollTop(). Less to go wrong and possibly faster.